# I can't use setter's in my javascript class because is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I try to use setter method with my class Test but my log return "TypeError: testObject.id is not a function"

```
class test {

    constructor() {
        this._id = 0;
    }

    get id(){
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(newId){
        this._id = newId;
    }
}

const testObject = new test();
console.log(testObject.id); // return 0
testObject.id(12); //return TypeError: myTest.id is not a function
console.log(testObject.id);
```

I expect the ouput will be 12 but i obtain TypeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a setter, you do assignment, you don't write a function call:

```
testObject.id = 12;
```

Live Example (I've also changed the name to `Test`; the *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is to capitalize constructor functions):

```js
class Test {

    constructor() {
        this._id = 0;
    }

    get id(){
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(newId){
        this._id = newId;
    }
}

const testObject = new Test();
console.log(testObject.id); // 0
testObject.id = 12;
console.log(testObject.id); // 12
```